# How to implement a unique ERC20 token for different assets

Tags: solidity, web3js, erc-20

I am trying to implement a way to tokenise real estate property. When a new property is added to the platform, the goal is to create a new instance of a `Property` and also create a new ERC20 token associated with that property.

I'm wondering what would be the best way to achieve this structure.

One solution I was working towards was having a contract erc20Factory, however, having multiple tokens would mean having a way to identify them and adding identification such as 'id' in every function would no longer meet the ERC20 standard. Is there another way to establish such association?

Would it be feasible for `Property` to store the address of its ERC20 token as an identifier?

Answer (score 0):

Super feasible and makes sense.  I'd have both an ID and an address as identifiers.  You could even have the ID be a hash of details of the property so people don't try and mint different tokens for the same property.